# mysql date range issue with values equal to 0 within dates period

Tags: mysql, date-range

please help me with this issue:
I have the following query:

```
select SUM(price) from prices_adverts 
                  where advert_id="15" 
                    and room_type_id="3" 
                    and (date >= "2013-09-20" AND date <"2013-09-23") 
order by price
```

This searches to find and SUM price for the room for dates between "2013-09-20" AND "2013-09-23"
but for example if dates 2013-09-21 and 2013-09-22 have value 0 and 2013-09-20 has value 25.00 the query will return sum of 25.00 for the whole date range. When the specific date has value 0 this means the room is not available, but when even 1 day has value greater than 0 the query accept the room as available because it has total value greater than 0.. Please advise me how to change the query so if even 1 day within daterange to has value 0 the query to return total value 0 for the whole period.. I hope you to understand the nature of this issue, thanks

Comment: Remove horizontal scroll from the query text be adding newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've missed `GROUP BY Room_id`. So it should be something like:

```
select room_id, 
       CASE WHEN MIN(price) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(price) END as priceSum
from prices_adverts 
     where advert_id="15" 
     and room_type_id="3" 
     and (date >= "2013-09-20" AND date <"2013-09-23") 
GROUP BY room_id
ORDER BY priceSum
```

Comment: Valex, on some reson the query blows, please check what is wrong with the expression

Comment: Valex room_id is room_type_id - this was the error, after I corrected the query returned result 16.00 which doesnt fit none of the price per date in the database.. how is this possible?

Comment: @thecore7: It returns SUM. If you need MAX then replace SUM with MAX

Comment: actially it returns room_type_id which is 16 and now instead of prices for period I have room_type_id EURO.. how to get total price instead room_type_id , sorry for being stupid :)

Comment: Valex thank you !, this was solved by Sashkello solution, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
IF(SUM(price = 0), 0, SUM(price))
```

And I assume you'd like to `GROUP BY room_id`.

Also I'd suggest changing those 0's in your database to NULLs. Because at some point you can possibly have 0 price, which is not equivalent to not available. You won't be able to distinguish them which is no good.

Comment: try how? can you please change to full query expression, please?

Comment: Replace your SUM(price) with this, that's all.

Comment: done and still returnes value because of that 1 day with greater 0 value, but I didn't change 0 to NULLs as you advised. Maybe this is the reason for not working? I can not change to NULLS because this is the way to recognize if room is available.. Zero value is used only for this purpose..